# Arduino SD card fails to write when used with another SPI device

Tags: arduino, sd-card, spi

I have an ADXL355 accelerometer attached to an Adafruit Feather Adalogger.  I can configure and read the sensor.  I can also write binary values to the SD card.  The problem occurs when I try to read from the sensor and then write that data to the SD card.  The only thing I can think of is I'm somehow messing up the SPI communication but I can't see where.  I looked through `pins_arduino.h` for my board and the SD Card (pin 4) is on a different register than pin 10 so I don't see how I'm breaking things.

My operations proceed like this.  Global sensor creation, `Serial.begin`, `SD.begin`, `SPI.begin`, Test sensor connection, Create file for output on SD card, Initialize sensor, Read sensor FIFO, Write to file, repeat last 2 forever.

The file is created but remains at 0 file size, ie nothing is actually written to the card.

The sensor can operate at 4 kHz which was hard to achieve using the `digitalWrite` functions so I switched to using the port registers on the Feather.  I do it like this:

```
#include <SM_ADXL355_SPI_fast.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>

#define cardSelect 4

ADXL355_SPIF adxl355(&DDRB, &PORTB, _BV(6)); // values taken from pins_arduino.h, tested and working on pin 10
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  while(!Serial){
    // wait for Serial
  }
  SD.begin(cardSelect);
  SPI.begin();
  while(!adxl355.TestConnection()){
    delay(1000);  
  }
  adxl355.OpenFile("TestSPI.bin");
  adxl355.Initialize(1, 10, 0); // set range to 2g's, frequency to 4 Hz and filter to off
}

void loop() {
  while(true){ // avoid Arduino overhead of their loop function
    adxl355.ReadFIFO();
    adxl355.WriteFIFOToFile();
  }
}
```

Here is the ADXL constructor

```
ADXL355_SPIF::ADXL355_SPIF(volatile uint8_t * outReg, volatile uint8_t * outPort, uint8_t bitValue) : sensorOutReg(outReg), sensorPort(outPort), sensorBitValue(bitValue){
    *sensorOutReg |= sensorBitValue;
    *sensorPort |= sensorBitValue;
    sensorWriteCount = 0;
}
```

`TestConnection` tests that the DeviceID reads `0xAD`.  `Initialize` sets the G range, sample rate in Hz and filter.  I have tested these with serial output and they work properly.

`OpenFile` looks like this:

```
bool ADXL355_SPIF::OpenFile(const String& fileName){
    sensorFile = SD.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);
    if (!sensorFile){
        Serial.print("Could not create file: ");
        Serial.println(fileName);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

After running this a file does get created on the SD card called "TESTSPI.BIN" with 0 file size.

`ReadFIFO` reads the numbers of entries in FIFO, stored as `fifoCount` and then populates a buffer (`sensorFIFO[32][3]`) with the values from the FIFO.  I've printed this buffer to Serial to show that it's working.  Here is that function

```
void ADXL355_SPIF::ReadFIFO(){
    ReadRegister(ADXL355_RA_FIFO_ENTRIES, 1);
    fifoCount = buffer[0];
    ReadFIFOInternal();
    return;
}

void ADXL355_SPIF::ReadFIFOInternal(){
    SPI.beginTransaction(SPISettings(10000000, MSBFIRST, SPI_MODE0));
    *sensorPort &= ~sensorBitValue;
    uint8_t spiCommand = ADXL355_RA_FIFO_DATA << 1 | ADXL355_READ;
    SPI.transfer(spiCommand);
    int i = 0;
    unsigned long tempV;
    unsigned long value;
    while(i < fifoCount){
        for (int ptr = 0; ptr < 3; ++ptr){
            buffer[0] = SPI.transfer(0x0);
            value = buffer[0];
            value <<= 12;
            tempV = SPI.transfer(0x0);
            tempV <<= 4;
            value |= tempV;
            tempV = SPI.transfer(0x0);
            tempV >>=4;
            value |= tempV;
            if (buffer[0] & 0x80) {
                value |= 0xFFF00000;
            }
            long lValue = static_cast<long>(value);
            sensorFIFO[i][ptr] = scaleFactor * lValue;
        }
        i += 3;
    }
    SPI.endTransaction();
    *sensorPort |= sensorBitValue;
    return;
}
```

Here is `WriteFIFOToFile`:

```
void ADXL355_SPIF::WriteFIFOToFile(){
    if (fifoCount > 0){
        sensorFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&sensorFIFO), 4 * fifoCount);
    }
    sensorWriteCount += fifoCount;
    if (sensorWriteCount >= 100){
        sensorFile.flush();
        sensorWriteCount = 0;
    }
}
```

After allowing this to run for a while the file size is always 0.  I tried a simple binary write function just to test the card.  It looks like this and it worked.

```
#include <SD.h>

#define cardSelectPin 4

const float pi=3.14159;

File oFile;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial){
    // wait for serial
  }
  SD.begin(cardSelectPin);
  oFile = SD.open("Test.bin", FILE_WRITE);
  Serial.println(sizeof(int));
  Serial.println(sizeof(float));
  float testFloat[32][3];
  for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j){
      testFloat[i][j] = pi * (i + 1) + j;
    }
  }
  oFile.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&testFloat), sizeof(float) * 96);
  oFile.close();
  Serial.println("Finished writing file.");
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

Comment: My problem is related to storing of data when i write the values on sd card the values are faulty however when i am not writing the values they are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `flush` was not being called correctly.  I had created a buffer to hold data from the FIFO and it would flush the card when it would get full enough such that a subsequent read would overflow.  At that time it would call `flush`.  This is what was intended with the variable `sensorWriteCount`.  This variable was of type `uint8_t` when it should have been a `uint16_t`.

Changing to the correct type fixed the problem.  I would have deleted this question because it boils down to a typo, but once an answer has been posted the system doesn't allow that.

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the not-working sketch and the working one is the closing of the sd card. The sd card MUST be closed, I had the same problem you have and I assume that the file gets its boundaries written in its filesystem at file close call.
To solve your issue, use a push button. When you push it, it will close the file and stop reading/processing sensors. You can also use this button to start reading and recording sensors data on sd card again (toggle).

Comment: This is not true.  If I remove the `close` statement the second sketch works exactly as before.  `flush` writes the buffer to the card.  Also the non-working sketch contains the `File` in the ADXL library which appears to be the problem.  If I move the `File` to be global I get data out.  This answer is just wrong.